# How to return redirect and have a backbutton, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this edit form and the back button is not working. So when I clicked the back button it shows this error

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\building.blade.php)

This is the backbutton for my createOffice I tried applying it to my EditOffice backbutton and it didnt work:

```
 <a href="{{ route('building', ['id' => $id] ) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

Also how do I make the UpdateOffice button when clicked it goes back to the page for the list of offices?

Here are the codes

OfficeController.php

```
public function index()
{

    $search = \Request::get('search');

    $offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
    return view('search')->with('offices', $offices)->with('search', $search);

  }

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function create($id)
{

    return view('createoffice')->with('id', $id);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $office = new Office();
    $office->name =$request->officename;
    $office->floor = $request->floor;
    $office->building_id = $id;
    $office->save();

     \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Created successfully!');

    return redirect()->back();


}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    return view('office')->withOffice($office);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    return view('editoffice')->withOffice($office)->with('id',$id);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    $office->name =$request->officename;
    $office->floor = $request->floor;
    $office->update();

      \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Updated successfully!');
return redirect()->back();

}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
        $office = Office::find($id);
        $office->delete();
\Session::flash('building_flash_delete', 'Deleted successfully!');
        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

PageController.php

```
    class PageController extends Controller
    {
        public function buildings(){
            $buildings = Building::paginate(10);
            return view('buildings')->with('buildings', $buildings);
        }

        public function show($id){
            $building = Building::find($id);
            $offices = Office::where('building_id', $id)->orderBy('floor')->get();
            return view('building')->with('building', $building)->with('offices', $offices);


    } }
```

Building.blade.php

```
  @extends('layouts.main')
  @section('title',$building->name)
  @section('css')
  @stop
  @section('content')

  <div class="officebg">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="Bldgttl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <img src="{{URL::to('/assets')}}/{{$building->picture}}" alt="" style="height:300px; width:500px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          {{$building->name}}
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="rows">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">
 @if(!Auth::guest())
                <a href="{{route('createofficeform', $building->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Create an Office</a>
  @endif
        </div>


      {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
      <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
       </button>
      </span>
        </div>
         {!! Form::close()!!}
          <hr>
    <table class="table">

      <thead>
          <th>Office Name</th>
          <th>Office Floor</th>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        @foreach($offices as $office)
          <tr>

            <td>{{$office->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$office->floor}}</td>
            <td class="a">
 @if(!Auth::guest())
              <a href="{{route('editofficeform', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
              <a href="{{route('deleteoffice', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
              @endif
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

    @endsection
```

Routes

```
Route::get('building/{id}/offices/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');

Route::post('building/{id}/offices/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');

Route::get('/', 'BuildingController@index')->name('index');

Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show')->name('building');

Route::get('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@show')->name('officeMenu');

Route::get('offices', 'OfficeController@index');
```

Comment: post building.blade.php code please

Comment: There I've Updated the code @ATechGuy

Answer (score 0):

you can use the back() command in your controller to return to the previous page.

```
return redirect->back();
```

Comment: nah it doesnt go back to the previous page it stays in the editform page after I click update @ATechGuy

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
return back()->with('success', 'message success');;
```

Comment: where di you want the back button redirect, to index of building or office.?

can you just redirect with route name
    return redirect(route('yourRouteName'));

in view blade
    <a href="{{ route('yourRouteName') }}" class="btn btn-info">back</a>

hope it helps

Comment: office @sancoLgates

Comment: I think I've tried that solution only the index is working I dunno why can you provide a code @sancoLgates

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.